# show gallery on tab selected android using library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-gallery

I currently have two tabs for show camera and gallery like instagram app.tabs are fragments. In the other words i have a viewpager and two tabs and in tabs fragments that i want to show camera and gallery. I am using [Mattise](https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse/) library for show gallery. 
My problem is showing gallery when click on gallery tab. My currently code just show gallery when i click on pick image button and dont show when i click to gallery tab.

This fragment code :

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE = 1001;
private static final int RESULT_OK = 1002;
private View view;
private static final int reqCode = 1000;

public static GalleryFragment newInstance() {
    GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
    return galleryFragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    Matisse.from(GalleryFragment.this)
            .choose(MimeType.allOf())
            .countable(true)
            .capture(false)
            .captureStrategy(
                    new CaptureStrategy(true, "com.zhihu.matisse.sample.fileprovider"))
            .maxSelectable(9)
            .gridExpectedSize(
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grid_expected_size))
            .restrictOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
            .imageEngine(new PicassoEngine())
            .forResult(REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE);

    return view;
}

List<Uri> mSelected;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mSelected = Matisse.obtainResult(data);
        Log.d("Matisse", "mSelected: " + mSelected);
    }
}

}
```

This code show gallery when I start activity, don't show when I clicking to gallery tablayout...

Comment: override setUserVisibleHint() and add your code in this callback if fragmeet is visible to user.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir ok thx man but it show gallery in another page and i want to show in tablayout

Comment: @PallaviTapkir please help me...

Comment: Matisse.from(GalleryFragment.this) change to   Matisse.from(getActivity())

Comment: @PallaviTapkir i want to show it in fragment... is there any way ? another library any code that help me?do you know ?thx sir.

Comment: Your fragment lies in context of your activity. So you have to pass activity context.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir thx i did it but it take full page for show gallery and i want to see tabs when gallery fragment(mattis library) i showing.
this is camera fragment: http://uupload.ir/files/jvgt_untitled2.png 
when i click to gallery : http://uupload.ir/files/mcro_untitled.png